# Android moving buttons upwards when showing snack bar

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-snackbar

I want to move my buttons upwards when showing snack bar, so it won't hide them. I've tried different solutions from stack overflow but I can't come up to the solution. This is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/fragment_expiry_dates_list_header" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/products_list"
        android:name="com.example.expirydate.ui.main.ExpiryDatesFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_above="@id/buttonNewOrOpened"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:context=".expirydatefragment.ExpiryDatesFragment"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_expiry_dates_list_item" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonNewOrOpened"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="New" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonUsed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/buttonNewOrOpened"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="Used" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonScanner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/buttonAdd"
        android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:contentDescription="scan product" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:contentDescription="add product" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What I would like to do is to move those 4 buttons on the bottom above snack bar. Code for showing snack bar:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content), "msg", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
snackbar.setAction("Undo", v -> {});
snackbar.show();
```

Currently it looks like this (there are 4 buttons hide on the bottom):
[image: current look]

I've tried several solutions with adding my own layout_behavior or adding app:insetEdges="bottom", but nothing worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were nearly in the right way when try using `app:insetEdges="bottom"`. But for first `insetEdges` and `layout_dodgeInsetEdges` work properly only with the `CoordinatorLayout`. You need to change your `RelativeLayout` to `CoordinatorLayout`. After that group your buttons in one layout, for example it can be `RelativeLayout` and add `app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="bottom"` and `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` to it. Since Snackbar by default has `app:insetEdges="bottom"` you were done only setting that properties to buttons container.

To make CoordinatorLayout work properly it's also supposed that your `header` is wrapped in `AppBarLayout` and add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to `RecyclerView`. Here I can provide the template for this solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- Your header here or your header need to be already wrapped in AppBarLayout -->

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/products_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:context=".expirydatefragment.ExpiryDatesFragment"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonsContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="bottom"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <!--Your Buttons here-->

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I should have added that presented by me layout is for the fragment that is part of this layout:
https://pastebin.com/3hsS6X2a

So the appbar is already included there. 

BTW why would I need to add appbar_scrolling_view_behavior to recycler view? I would only want to move up the buttons that are on the bottom.

Comment: If you don't add appbar_scrolling_view_behavior to RecyclerView, it will overlap the AppBarLayout.

Comment: So I've tried something like this:
https://pastebin.com/V8ZaGYJe

But it won't work and I cannot come up why :(

I've even tried to add this test text view at the bottom but it won't go up when snack bar is shown

Comment: what view you pass to Snackbar make method as first parameter? I see you use R.id.content but can't find any view with that id. Set that id to any of CoordinatorLayout child and try again.

Comment: Yeah, that seemed to be the problem! I've changed it to getActivity().findViewById(R.id.expiry_date_layout), and set the relative layout id to expiry_date_layout.

Comment: Yes it's working now with one problem.

One more question, what should I do to avoid recycler view swipping under the app bar? So basically I would like to shrink the size of recycler view during showing snack bar, rather then moving it up.

Comment: But now when showing snack bar, it will move up only the TextView and overlap on RecycleView rather then move it up too.

Comment: Oh okay, that's probably because I've added insetDodgeEdges on the relative layout. I would change that, but I'm not sure how in coordinator layout I can make recycler view on the top and stretch to the bottom above buttons but not hide them?